# Computing device's angle

Tags: android-studio, accelerometer, magnetometer

I'd like to  compute my device's angle, when it's tilted at the bottom edges to the left and right, using the accelerometer and magnetometer. Then save the highest value I've received and show it in a TextView.

This is how I tried:

```
 public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
        mGravity = event.values;
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD)
        mGeomagnetic = event.values;
    if (mGravity != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
        float R[] = new float[9];
        float I[] = new float[9];

        boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mGravity, mGeomagnetic);
        if (success) {
            float orientation[] = new float[3];
            SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
            playerAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(orientation[3]);

            tv.setText(String.valueOf(playerAngle));


        }
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information about what you tried? Did you use the [SensorManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html) class? You just need to save the values inside the onSensorChanged function. Did you get any values at all, or the wrong values?

Comment: edited my question.

Comment: So, what is going wrong? Are the values wrong or do you not get any? Are you registering listeners for both TYPE_ACCELEROMETER and TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD?

Comment: BTW, if you just want the angle you could try registering Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION and saving event.values[2], which is a roll angle in radians

Comment: I´d like to set the value of orientation[3] to a TextView, but everytime i debugg the app the TextView doesn´t show any value.

Comment: And both listeners are registered.

Comment: If you put a Log statement inside onSensorChanged logging the values does anything get output?

Comment: You should output orientation[2] not orientation[3]

Comment: I tried but the values were too vague and it often went from 30° to 70° holding the device at the same angle.

Comment: I tried but the values were too vague and it often went from 30° to 70° holding the device at the same angle.

Comment: Accelerometer values are very noisy on many devices. You can apply a simple low-pass filter component-wise to mGravity and mGeomagnetic e.g. new_value = (old_value * 0.9) + (sensor_value * 0.1)

Comment: I´ll try. Thanks.